# How to use ellipsis in a table cell?

Tags: html, css, html-table, flexbox, ellipsis

```
<div className="container">
  <div className="left-area">
    <div className="container2">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              48148581581581858158158iffjafjadjfjafdjafdjfjadfjdjafdjafdjajdfjadfjdafjdajfajfdjaf
            </td>
            <td>1/1/0001</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to truncate that very long text.

```
.container {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  .left-area {
    flex: 1 1 20%;
    .container2 {
      flex: 1 1 20%;
      table {
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to use this css on the `td cell`

```
  white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Comment: you mean "how to ellipse text in table cell"? maybe you should look in the `text-overflow: ellipsis;` property

Comment: Yes in the table cell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The missing key is `table-layout: fixed`.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
  width: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        48148581581581858158158iffjafjadjfjafdjafdjfjadfjdjafdjafdjajdfjadfjdafjdajfajfdjaf
      </td>
      <td>1/1/0001</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

With `table-layout: auto` (the default setting), the browser uses an automatic layout algorithm that checks the content size to set the width of the cells (and, therefore, columns).
The `width` and `overflow` properties are ignored in this scenario, and ellipsis can't work.

With `table-layout: fixed`, you can define the width of the cells on the first row (and, therefore, set the column widths for the table).
The `width` and `overflow` properties are respected in this case, allowing the ellipsis function to work.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout

Comment: I tested it and indeed, ellipses only worked with `fixed`, but it was not an ordinary plain `<table>` but a Javascript grid widget library-generated table, so setting `fixed` made the library malfunction. I do not understand why ellipses logically cannot work with auto sizing. I mean, with auto sizing, when the text is long (not unbreakable string like OP), it gets word-wrapped in multiple lines. Can't the browser simply show the first line of that with an ellipses and hide other lines?